# Unable to edit textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to edit my `textarea` manually after updating it with JavaScript, but when I write some text on it, the text I write is positioned over the text which is already in the `textarea` (written by JS).

So I'm searching of why can't I do it. Here is my code:

```js
function initTextIA() {
  var txt = document.createElement('textarea');
  txt.style.rows = "5";
  txt.style.cols = "45";
  txt.style.top = "2300px";
  txt.style.left = "250px";
  txt.style.position = "absolute";
  txt.style.background = "none";
  txt.style.color = "green";
  txt.id = "txtIA";
  document.getElementById("cool").appendChild(txt);
}


initTextIA();

var doc = document.getElementById("txtIA")
doc.value += "txtxtxtxt.\n";
```

```html
<div id="cool"></div>
```

The resulting HTML code of the `textarea` is :

```
<textarea id="txtIA" style="top: 2300px; left: 250px; position: absolute; background: none; color: green;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is going wrong? Not sure I understand.

Comment: Is there some HTML going with this? I dont understand either.

Comment: The problem is : there is a text in the textarea which has been written by js, and when I manually write something in the textarea, the text written is over the text already wrote by js. And I don't want this

Comment: Even whilst trying with just some basic HTML the above code seems to work. What is your expectation here? You'll get `txtxtxtxt.\n` in the JS generated `textarea`.

Comment: yes but when I write something manually in the textarea, the text is over the text written by js

Comment: add an onfocus that clears the text if it is equal to the default text

Comment: @vinny76 you need to include your HTML and CSS.

Comment: There are no html code, all have to be written by js (I'm not allowed to write in html because this is my school project)

Comment: @vinny76 The code provided only runs once on load. You must be re-running the `doc.value=xxx` JS then, from another function. This would re-set it back to whatever is defined in the JS. Please post the minimum code/HTML to replicate this.

Comment: @vinny76 there's got to be some other code, you can't use your `getElementById()` calls without it. Not only that, but what's calling `initTextIA()` to begin with? You really should provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, I update it with the html code given by js

Comment: @vinny76 you're absolute positioning is the same for your initial `textarea` and as it is for your JS created `textarea`. Absolute positioned items take up no space and are being placed one on top of another. If you remove the absolute positioning the generated `textarea` should be placed after, not before, the original `textarea`.

Comment: @hungerstar is there a way to manually edit the text written by js?

Comment: @hungerstar - I think the HTML given here is the _output_ from the JS hence why there would be two (the CSS generated is all specified in the JS style properties). 
OP - you can *always* overtype the text generated by JS unless its read only or some other event overrides. Have you got a jsfiddle where we can replicate your issue? It would seem that the textarea is being overwritten by some other event when you type, but this is pure guesswork as-is.

Comment: @G0dsquad perhaps. vinny76 is a bit unclear on some of the specifics, like how/when is `initTextAI()` being called. But what he's describing sounds like two absolute positioned elements stacked on top of one another.

Comment: Now I know where the problem is : the position absolute makes me overwritting above the current text written by js. But now I try to find a way to keep the text in the same place but updatable

Comment: @G0dsquad we really need  a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would clear a lot of things up. Plus a little more info on intended outcome. It sounds like he might be intentionally creating two `textarea` with a possibility of not needing to. Hard to know at this point.

Comment: Yep - looks like you have some more clarity now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From comments it sounds to me like your line-height property is not properly set for textarea. Since you set textarea value with line break on the end:

> txtxtxtxt.\n

newly written text should go in second row but it overlaps old text entered with JS. So try the following inside your initTextIA function:

```
txt.style.lineHeight = "2";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code you gave me, but What I wanted is to manually update the text written by js

Comment: So you want old text to clear when you click on textarea so you can start writing new text?

Comment: no, just being able to manually add or copy text from the textarea. For example if the js wrote "blabla" I'd like to be able to do "blahello"

Comment: Im confused. If you only want to achieve that new text is added immediately after text added by JS remove "\n" from doc.value += "txtxtxtxt.\n".

Answer (score 0):

Since there is little original HTML provided in question so there are a lot of assumptions here. What I feel from all the discussion in comments is you are not able to append text then type in a value then continue appending it via some button.

I have written a simple case where I have commented out the positioning of textarea so testing can be done with ease. I have added two buttons but no error checks just to give a direction. Please let me know if this does not resolve the issue.

```js
function initTextIA() {
            var txt = document.createElement('textarea');
            txt.style.rows = "5";
            txt.style.cols = "45";
            //txt.style.top = "2300px";
            //txt.style.left = "250px";
            //txt.style.position = "absolute";
            txt.style.background = "none";
            txt.style.color = "green";
            txt.id = "txtIA";
            document.getElementById("cool").appendChild(txt);
            document.getElementById('addButton').style = 'display:none';
            document.getElementById('appendButton').style = 'display:block';
            
}

function fillTextIA() {
var doc = document.getElementById("txtIA")
doc.value += "txtxtxtxt.\n";
}
```

```html
<div>
<button id='addButton' onclick='initTextIA()'>add text area</button>
<button id='appendButton' onclick='fillTextIA()' style='display:none'>append text</button>
</div>
<div id='cool'>
<p>An element.</p>
</div>
```